# Using nextjs with thirdparty api httpOnly cookie

Tags: api, next.js, httponly

I have a nodejs-express REST API which is using httpOnly cookie for authorization . I am using nextjs as front-end for my API.
My question : is there any middleware/package that I should use to check whether the user is authorized to see the pages by checking if the thirdparty api is already set the cookie for the user ? or I should manually check the user's cookies ?